# SoundManager 2 Slider UI while sliding not changing anything - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider, soundmanager2

I have a problem with plugin SoundManager + Slider jquery UI - this one works as volume/current position changer while playing music.

After page is loaded, sometimes (i think it depends on file size) volume and current position are works fine, but if file are too huge, slider is loading properly (no errors in console) but not changing anything.

```
  <?php
// In page Javascript
function audio_player_javascript () {
?>
    <script>
        var AudioPlayerDebugMode = true;
        var songPlays = 0;
        function AudioPlayerConsole (message) {
            if (AudioPlayerDebugMode == true)
                console.log(message);       
        }

    function convertMilliseconds (ms, p) {

            var pattern = p || "hh:mm:ss",
                arrayPattern = pattern.split(":"),
                clock = [ ],
                hours = Math.floor ( ms / 3600000 ), // 1 Hour = 36000 Milliseconds
                minuets = Math.floor (( ms % 3600000) / 60000), // 1 Minutes = 60000 Milliseconds
                seconds = Math.floor ((( ms % 360000) % 60000) / 1000) // 1 Second = 1000 Milliseconds

            // build the clock result
            function createClock(unit){


            // match the pattern to the corresponding variable
            if (pattern.match(unit)) {
                if (unit.match(/h/)) {
                    addUnitToClock(hours, unit);
                }
                if (unit.match(/m/)) {
                    addUnitToClock(minuets, unit);
                }
                if (unit.match(/s/)) {
                    addUnitToClock(seconds, unit);
                };
                }
            }

            function addUnitToClock(val, unit){

                if ( val < 10 && unit.length === 2) {
                    val = "0" + val;
                }

                clock.push(val); // push the values into the clock array

            }


            // loop over the pattern building out the clock result
            for ( var i = 0, j = arrayPattern.length; i < j; i ++ ){

                createClock(arrayPattern[i]);

            }

            return {
                hours : hours,
                minuets : minuets,
                seconds : seconds,
                clock : clock.join(":")
            };

    }

    <?php
    $detect = new Mobile_Detect();
    if ($detect->isMobile()) 
    { 
    ?>
        setTimeout(function () {jQuery(".audio-player-toggle").trigger("click");}, 1000);

    <?php
    }

    if (get_option("audio_player_autoplay_plugin") == "yes")
    {
    ?>

        setTimeout(function () { jQuery("#play-pause-button").trigger("click"); }, 1000);
    <?php
    }
    ?>



    jQuery(function() {
        soundManager.url = "<?php echo plugins_url('/js/soundmanager/swf', __FILE__);?>";


        // Hide audio player
        jQuery(".audio-player-toggle.open").live("click", function (e) {
            jQuery(".audio-player-container").animate({
                bottom: '-' + jQuery(".audio-player-container").height() + 'px'
            }, 300, function () {
                jQuery(".audio-player-toggle").removeClass("open");
                jQuery(".audio-player-toggle").addClass("closed");
            });
        });

        // Show audio player
        jQuery(".audio-player-toggle.closed").live("click", function (e) {
            jQuery(".audio-player-container").animate({
                bottom: '0px'
            }, 300, function () {
                jQuery(".audio-player-toggle").removeClass("closed");
                jQuery(".audio-player-toggle").addClass("open");
            });
        });

        jQuery( "#position-scrubber" ).slider({
            range: "max",
            min: 0,
            max: 0,
            value: 0,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {

            }
        });

        if (navigator.mimeTypes ["application/x-shockwave-flash"] != undefined)
        {
            // Set volume range if browser has Flash enabled
            jQuery( "#volume-scrubber" ).slider({
                range: "max",
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                value: 50,
                slide: function( event, ui ) {

                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            // Set volume range if browser doesn't have Flash enabled
            jQuery( "#volume-scrubber" ).slider({
                range: "max",
                min: 0,
                max: 1,
                value: 0.5,
                step: 0.01,
                slide: function( event, ui ) {

                }
            }); 
        }

        jQuery(".audio-controls-container a").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        var htmlSound = new Audio ();

        // Set first song in playlist to be played
        jQuery(".playlist_item:first").addClass("current");

        var firstSong;
        var mySound;

        // Find playlist item with current class
        firstSong = jQuery(".playlist_item:first").attr("data-song_file");


        jQuery("#play-pause-button").live("click", function (e) {
            AudioPlayerConsole(songPlays);
            if (songPlays == 0)
            {

                playAudio(firstSong);
                jQuery(this).addClass("playing");

            }
            else
            {
                // Pause music if it has playing class
                if (jQuery(this).hasClass("playing"))
                {
                    AudioPlayerConsole("stop playing");
                    jQuery(this).removeClass("playing");

                    if (navigator.mimeTypes["application/x-shockwave-flash"] != undefined)
                        mySound.pause('audio-player');
                    else
                        htmlSound.pause();
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    AudioPlayerConsole("start playing");
                    jQuery(this).addClass("playing");


                    if (navigator.mimeTypes ["application/x-shockwave-flash"] != undefined)
                        mySound.resume('audio-player');
                    else
                        htmlSound.play();
                    return; 
                }
            }

        });


        jQuery("#next-button").live("click", function (e) {
            var thisSongFile = jQuery(".playlist_item.current").next(".playlist_item").attr("data-song_file");
            if(!thisSongFile)
            {
                jQuery(".playlist_item").removeClass("current");
                jQuery(".playlist_item:first").addClass("current");
                thisSongFile = jQuery(".playlist_item:first").attr("data-song_file");
                playAudio(thisSongFile);
            }
            else
            {
                console.log(thisSongFile);
                var foundCurrent = false;
                jQuery(".playlist_item").each(function () {
                    if (foundCurrent == true)
                    {
                        jQuery(this).addClass("current");
                        foundCurrent = false;
                        return; 
                    }

                    if (jQuery(this).hasClass("current"))
                    {
                        jQuery(this).removeClass("current");
                        foundCurrent = true;    
                    }
                });
                playAudio(thisSongFile);

            }
        });

        jQuery("#previous-button").live("click", function (e) {
            var thisSongFile = jQuery(".playlist_item.current").prev(".playlist_item").attr("data-song_file");
            if(!thisSongFile)
            {
                jQuery(".playlist_item").removeClass("current");
                jQuery(".playlist_item:first").addClass("current");
                thisSongFile = jQuery(".playlist_item:first").attr("data-song_file");
                playAudio(thisSongFile);
            }
            else
            {

                var foundCurrent = false;
                jQuery(".playlist_item").each(function () {
                    if (jQuery(this).hasClass("current"))
                    {
                        jQuery(this).removeClass("current");
                        jQuery(this).prev(".playlist_item").addClass("current");    
                    }
                });
                playAudio(thisSongFile);

            }
        });

        // Load album track preview into audio player
        jQuery(".track-preview").live("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var thisSongFile = jQuery(this).attr("data-song_file");
            var thisSongArtist = jQuery(this).attr("data-song_artist");
            var thisSongTitle =  jQuery(this).attr("data-song_title");

            var isInPlaylist = false;
            // Determine if selected song is already in playlist
            jQuery(".playlist_item").each(function () {

                // Get title and artist of playing song
                var songTitle = jQuery(this).attr("data-song_title");
                var songArtist = jQuery(this).attr("data-song_artist");

                if (thisSongArtist == songArtist && thisSongTitle == songTitle)
                {
                    jQuery(".playlist_item").removeClass("current");
                    jQuery(this).addClass("current");
                    isInPlaylist = true;
                }

            });

            if (isInPlaylist == true)
            {
                playAudio(thisSongFile);
            }
            else
            {
                jQuery(".playlist_item").removeClass("current");
                var newPlaylistItem = '<li class="playlist_item current" song_title="' + thisSongTitle + '" song_artwork="" song_file="' + thisSongFile + '" song_artist="' + thisSongArtist + '"></li>';
                jQuery("#audio-player-playlist").append(newPlaylistItem);
                playAudio(thisSongFile);
            }

        });

        function playAudio (songFile) {
    songPlays++;
    AudioPlayerConsole("Loading " + songFile);
    if (navigator.mimeTypes ["application/x-shockwave-flash"] != undefined)
    {   
        soundManager.onready(function() {   
            soundManager.destroySound('audio-player');
            mySound = soundManager.createSound({
                id:'audio-player',
                url: songFile,
                onload: function() {
                    var duration = mySound.duration;
                    jQuery( "#position-scrubber" ).slider("option", "max", duration);
                    var durationTime = convertMilliseconds(duration, "mm:ss");
                    jQuery("#total-track-time").html(durationTime.clock);
                    jQuery( "#position-scrubber" ).bind( "slide", function(event, ui) {
                        mySound.setPosition(ui.value);
                    });

                    // Show pause button
                    jQuery("#play-pause-button").addClass("playing");


                },
                whileplaying: function() {
                    var position = mySound.position;
                    var positionTime = convertMilliseconds(position, "mm:ss");
                    jQuery("#current-track-time").html(positionTime.clock);
                    jQuery( "#position-scrubber" ).slider("option", "value", position/1000);
                    var volume = jQuery( "#volume-scrubber" ).slider("option", "value");
                    mySound.setVolume(volume);
                },
                whileloading: function() {
                    var duration = mySound.duration;
                    var durationTime = convertMilliseconds(duration, "mm:ss");
                    jQuery("#total-track-time").html(durationTime.clock);

                },
                 onfinish: function() {
                    // Play next song in playlist
                    setTimeout(function () {jQuery("#next-button").trigger("click");}, 300);
                 }


            });
            // End soundManager.createSound

            mySound.play();


        });
        jQuery("#play-pause-button").addClass("playing");

    }
    // End if (navigator.mimeTypes ["application/x-shockwave-flash"] != undefined)
    else
    // Player will use HTML5
    {
        htmlSound.src = songFile;
        htmlSound.load();

        jQuery( "#position-scrubber" ).bind( "slide", function(event, ui) {
            htmlSound.currentTime = ui.value;
        });

        htmlSound.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
            var newVolume = jQuery( "#volume-scrubber" ).slider("option", "value");
            htmlSound.volume = newVolume;

            var duration = htmlSound.duration * 1000;
            var durationTime = convertMilliseconds(duration, "mm:ss");
            jQuery("#total-track-time").html(durationTime.clock );

            var position = htmlSound.currentTime * 1000;
            var positionTime = convertMilliseconds(position, "mm:ss");
            jQuery("#current-track-time").html(positionTime.clock );

            jQuery( "#position-scrubber" ).slider("option", "max", duration/1000);
            jQuery( "#position-scrubber" ).slider("option", "value", position/1000);

        });

        htmlSound.addEventListener("ended", function() {
            setTimeout(function () {jQuery("#next-button").trigger("click");}, 300);
        }); 

        htmlSound.play();
        jQuery("#play-pause-button").addClass("playing");
    }
    // End Player will use HTML5

    jQuery(".playlist_item").each(function () {
        if (jQuery(this).hasClass("current"))
        {
            // Set title, artist, and artwork of playing song
            var songArtwork = jQuery(this).attr("data-song_artwork");
            var songTitle = jQuery(this).attr("data-song_title");
            var songArtist = jQuery(this).attr("data-song_artist");

            if (songArtwork != "")
            {
                jQuery(".audio-player-artwork img").attr("src", songArtwork);
                jQuery(".audio-player-artwork").show();
            }
            else
            {
                jQuery(".audio-player-artwork img").attr("src", "");
                jQuery(".audio-player-artwork").hide();
            }

            jQuery(".audio-player-song-title").html(songTitle);
            jQuery(".audio-player-song-artist").html(songArtist);
        }
    });


}
        // End playAudio()
    });
</script>
```